# Adding Array values to a Bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, google-cloud-firestore

I have a name[10] array and a score[10] array inside a script in a html file that uses both Bootstrap 4 and Firebase's FireStore.

Is there a way to pass the array variables into the table, as currently the table only seems to accept string values, rather than variables.

```
<script>
        var nameArray =  Array.from(querySnapshot.docs, x => x.data().name);

        var scoreArray =  Array.from(querySnapshot.docs, x => x.data().score);
```

//Outputs values into

format

```
document.getElementById("0").innerHTML = "Name "+ " | " + "Score";
document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = nameArray[0] + " | " + scoreArray[0];  
document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = nameArray[1] + " | " + scoreArray[1];
document.getElementById("3").innerHTML = nameArray[2] + " | " + scoreArray[2];  
document.getElementById("4").innerHTML = nameArray[3] + " | " + scoreArray[3];      
document.getElementById("5").innerHTML = nameArray[4] + " | " + scoreArray[4];  
document.getElementById("6").innerHTML = nameArray[5] + " | " + scoreArray[5];      
document.getElementById("7").innerHTML = nameArray[6] + " | " + scoreArray[6];  
document.getElementById("8").innerHTML = nameArray[7] + " | " + scoreArray[7];      
document.getElementById("9").innerHTML = nameArray[8] + " | " + scoreArray[8];
document.getElementById("10").innerHTML = nameArray[9] + " | " + scoreArray[9]; 



</script>

<div class="container-fluid">        
  <table class="table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Score</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>26</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Dave</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<p id="0"></p>
<p id="1"></p>
<p id="2"></p>
<p id="3"></p>
<p id="4"></p>
<p id="5"></p>
<p id="6"></p>
<p id="7"></p>
<p id="8"></p>
<p id="9"></p>
<p id="10"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an id to the table, and use `getElementById()` to get the table element and then inside the `<script>` itself you may use variables to fill the values into the `<td>variable</td>` and insert this tags into the element using `innerHtml`

```
    <script>
      var table = document.getElementById('tableContents');
      var tableContents = '<tr><td>'+nameArray[0]+'</td><td>'+scoreArray[0]+'</td></tr>';
      table.innerHTML = tableContents;
    </script>


  <div class="container-fluid">        
      <table class="table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Score</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id='tableContents'>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: I added an id to the table, and I managed to get the variables of the array printing out to a `<p>` using `document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = nameArray[0] + " | " + scoreArray[0]; ` But when I tried using that for the table values it didn't seem to work

Comment: The innerHtml string value should be exactly same to the contents of the example you posted above except that you should use your variable names instead of the values in the <td>

Comment: So should I copy the structure of the BootStrap table into the <script>? I will update the code as to what I have now as I don't understand what you mean, could you add an example?

Comment: Thanks! That worked, I just had to change the innerHtml suffix to the correct Syntax (innerHTML).